# how to fix mouse simulator not working with python in desktop app

Tags: python, automation, trading

I have a problem with mouse simulator in this desktop application name "ticker chart".

I tried alot and I don't know what's problem, why I can't click mouse and type my string text in Search bar ticker chart .

I am running ticker chart as administrator and it shows the same problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RucmH.png)

```
 import pyautogui as pg
 from PIL import Image
 from pytesseract import *
 import pywinauto , time
 from pywinauto.application import Application
 from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys
 import win32api , win32con

 def click(x,y):
   win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
   win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
   win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)
   pg.press("Enter")
   pg.click(x,y)
   time.sleep(5)
   pg.typewrite("1212")
 click(655, 153)
```

I want to click on the search bar and type the symbol stock ksa.